# Cleaning HTML with Nokogiri (instead of Tidy)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, tidy

The `tidy` gem is no longer maintained and has multiple memory leak issues.

Some people suggested using Nokogiri.

I'm currently cleaning the HTML using:

`Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html).to_html`

I've got two issues though:

- Nokogiri removes the `DOCTYPE`
- Is there an easy way to force the cleaned HTML to have a `html` and `body` tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are processing a full document, you want:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html).to_html
```

That will force `html` and `body` tags, and introduce or preserve the `DOCTYPE`:

```
puts Nokogiri::HTML('<p>Hi!</p>').to_html
#=> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
#=>  "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
#=> <html><body><p>Hi!</p></body></html>

puts Nokogiri::HTML('<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hi!</p>').to_html
#=> <!DOCTYPE html>
#=> <html><body><p>Hi!</p></body></html>
```

Note that the output is not guaranteed to be syntactically valid. For example, if I provide a broken document that lies and claims that it is HTML4.01 strict, Nokogiri will output a document with that DOCTYPE but without the required `<head><title>...</title></head>` section:

```
dtd = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'
puts Nokogiri::HTML("#{dtd}<p>Hi!</p>").to_html
#=> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
#=>  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
#=> <html><body><p>Hi!</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Wow. I should have looked a bit harder. Thanks a bunch. :) On a side note, do you have any comments on how Nokogiri performs versus Tidy? Or maybe you have a suggestion of a Ruby lib that cleans HTML better?

Comment: @Christian I have no experience with Tidy, Rubyful Soup, Hpricot, or any other library for tidying HTML. Nokogiri is my toolkit of choice for all things HTML and XML, though I am almost always dealing with syntactically-valid markup.

Answer (score 2):

The Tidy gem might not be supported, but the underlying [`tidy` app is maintained](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), and that is what you really need. It's flexible and has quite a [list of options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html).

You can pass HTML to it in many different ways, and define its configuration in a `.tidyrc` file or pass them on the command-line. You could use Ruby's `%x{}` to pass it a file or use `IO.popen`, or `IO.pipe` to treat it as a pipe.

Comment: Yeah that was another option I had in mind, but I wanted to avoid creating a sub-process each time.

Comment: Then use IO.pipe and hold it open. You'd only have to do it one time for the entire app session.

Comment: @Christian Joudrey I just found someone is working on a new tidy for Ruby: https://github.com/carld/tidy