# Template language for Markdown to Markdown

Tags: yaml, markdown, template-engine, pandoc

I'm looking for a simple templating engine that takes a YAML snipped as context and works well for reading Markdown plus some tags to produce Markdown. I tried Jekyll's Liquid and it works, except for whitespace which is really important in Markdown.

For example with this input...

```
---
samples:
- name: one
  samplecode: |
    function sample() {
      return 1;
    }
- name: two
  samplecode: |
    function sample() {
      return 2;
    }
---

{% for s in page.samples %}
- {{s.name}}

        {{s.samplecode}}

{% endfor %}
```

the output is:

```
- one

        function sample() {
  return 1;
}

- two

        function sample() {
  return 2;
}
```

instead of the following which would actually work with Pandoc:

```
- one

        function sample() {
          return 1;
        }

- two

        function sample() {
          return 2;
        }
```

This has actually been [discussed before for Jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646945/indenting-generated-markup-in-jekyll-ruby#comment36154794_13646945).

So my question: is there any simple template engine that suits my needs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could use the template engine built into pandoc to do what you want to do.

`t.tpl`:

```
$for(samples)$
-   $samples.name$

    $samples.samplecode$

$endfor$
```

`t.md`:

````
---
samples:
- name: one
  samplecode: |
    ```
    function sample() {
      return 1;
    }
    ```
- name: two
  samplecode: |
    ```
    function sample() {
      return 2;
    }
    ```
---
````

Note:  we put the code samples in code fences because pandoc interprets metadata values as markdown.

Then:

```
% pandoc --template t.tpl -f markdown -t markdown t.md
-   one

        function sample() {
          return 1;
        }

-   two

        function sample() {
          return 2;
        }
```

Comment: Oh wow, Pandoc never ceases to amaze me! (I quickly searched for "loop" in the README but didn't find it so I assumed it wasn't possible...)

Comment: The only downside for my usecase is that it's kind of the wrong way around (text embedded in the template instead of loop used to generate text). I'm writing a text and at one point in the text I need to generate this text. But I guess I can just invert everything and it's going to work...

Comment: If you know any Haskell (even just a little), you can use the `Text.Pandoc.Builder` module in pandoc-types to generate pandoc documents programmatically from data, and then use pandoc's markdown writer to convert it to markdown.  If what you're doing is complex, that might be a better solution.